# Hudson workspace locked while building

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson, polling

I am facing a problem recently with my CI environment.

I am using **Hudson ver. 1.395.1** and **SVN ver  1.4.2.**

My Hudson is continuously polling the SVN for any changes, and if so it kicks off a build.

Recently this operation fails with the below message

```
Updating https://MY_SVN_URL/trunk
Workspace appear to be locked, so getting a fresh workspace
Checking out https:/MY_SVN_URL/trunk
ERROR: Failed to check out https://MY_SVN_URL/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Working copy '/Hudson/workspace/MY_PROJECT_NAME' locked; try performing 'cleanup'
```

It has to be noted that this only happens when i commit changes and Hudson is trying to trigger a build (by polling the SVN). The problem does not happen when i manually trigger the build.

It seems to me that the polling is locking the Hudson workspace and the update operation is finding the workspace locked.

Has anyone been to the same situation before? Any solutions to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would answer my own question, as this maybe useful for other people.

The root cause of this, was actually something very simple. The server that Hudson runs on, was rebooted 3-4 days prior to this incident.

It was found out, that two instances of Hudson were running on the machine. So one instance was acquiring and holding lock making the other to fail intermmitently.

Funny thing is that despite the server re-started 3 days ago, the problem came up today.

So just for further reference if someone ever faces this kind of a problem better check first the above simple thing, before spending too much time like me.

Answer (score 2):

I want to say this often happens to me when I **abort** an action after I started it ( Ex : a project build that add/change files...), or aborting a Hudson job.

If aborting is the cause, you can verify at your Workspace level where you have the folder **.svn**, by trying a revert and so you will get this message :

```
working copy <project_name> locked
```

And so we can say the 2 problems are related (the one at Hudson level, and the other sent SVN level).

To get red of it, and if your using TortoiseSVN :

1. Right click on the checked out folder
2. TortoiseSVN
3. Clean Up
4. Check these options : Clean up working copy status+Include externals